# IP Block Regex for Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Please can someone help me write a regex to validate an IP BLock eg. 196.126.0.1/29.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried with.

Comment: Do you want to validate if it is valid subnetting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the IP is correct you can use the following expression :

```
 ^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\/\d{1,2}$
```

`\d{1,3}\.` check that you have one to three digit following with a dot.

`(\d{1,3}\.){3}` repeteat the test three time.

`\d{1,3}\/\d{1,2}` last IP digits following with a slash and a port number (change the max number of digit if the port may be more than two digit).